# Loop over ul in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am generating a list of elements li with the name `keywords[]` and I want to store each individual `li` value within mySQL DB. With my current code, I always only have 1 row created with "`Array`" in the `keyword` column. This is how it looks like on the db: [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fyd9J.png)

How can I loop over every li element and store every value in a different row? thank you for your time.

**add-jobs.php**

```
</p>
    <div class="add">
        <label for="keywords">Keywords : </label>     
        <input type="text" class="keywords" name="keyword" value=""/>   
        <button class="add-keyword">Add</button>               
    </div>
        <ul class="list-keywords">
        <li>Apple<input type='hidden' name='keywords[]' value='Apple'/></li>
        <li>Pear<input type='hidden' name='keywords[]' value='Pear'/></li>
        <li>Banana<input type='hidden' name='keywords[]' value='Banana'/></li>
        </ul>
<p>
```

**add-database.php**

```
<?php
    require("../config/db.php");
    require("add-jobs.php");

    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","benoit");

    $keywords = $_POST["keywords"];

mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO keywords (`keyword`) VALUES ('$keywords')");

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Vulnerable to SQL Injection**

`$keywords` contains an array, that's why you see 'array' inserted in your DB. You only have one record because you're only inserting one record.

Loop through the `$keywords` array and `INSERT` after each iteration.

```
foreach ($keywords as $k)
{
    mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO keywords (`keyword`) VALUES ('$k')");
}
```

Comment: you should use prepared statement when you do a db query, to avoid SQL injections

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm just giving him the simple reason why he's only getting one record, I'm not going to explain out all the faults.

Comment: Thank you guys. I haven't protected my code yet against SQL injections. The thing is I started to learn MySQL and PHP 2 weeks ago and it's already a lot. I want to have a code that is working then protect it against SQL injections

Comment: @Sophia2000 That's how I do things as well. Get the basics, working and understand what's happening. Once that's good, then to the next part. Once you get the hang of it, you will write the code with protection right away. Good luck!